# Правильно ли говорить?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Правильно ли говорить: " Я его (её)очень сильно люблю" и " Он очень большой молодец"?

Answer (score 2):

Если Вы хотите так сказать, и это - самая настоящая правда, то нет никаких препятствий на подобные высказывания. Искреннее выражение своих чувств никто не может ни запретить, ни регламентировать! Говорите, и почаще говорите...
Мне иногда становится забавно : люди стали бояться своего родного языка? Или они перестали понимать друг друга :
"Я тебя очень сильно люблю!" - "Ты что, ... , с ума сошел? Где ты, ... , нахватался таких, ... , слов-то..."

Comment: А если сказать "Я тебя очень люблю"- это не искреннее выражение чувств? По-моему, "люблю" и "сильно" как-то не очень.

Comment: Если *не очень*, тогда действительно не стоит.

Answer (score 1):

Так говорят"рожденные" в ДОМе2.
Это нормально,это ....увы...нормально...